# Loop dequeue in list of three items in.NET

Tags: c#, .net, loops, queue

I have a queue of type string containing 18 elements, but this may vary.

**My code:**

```
var items = new List<BaseClass>();

Queue<string> queuestr = new Queue<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
{
    queuestr.Enqueue("line - " + i.ToString());
}

for (int i = 0; i < queuestr.Count; i++)
{
    items.Add(new queuestrtem
    {
        Item1 = queuestr.Dequeue(),
        Item2 = queuestr.Dequeue(),
        Item3 = queuestr.Dequeue(),
    });
}
```

**What it does:**

queuestr dequeues one string at a time to `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3`, at the end `items` contains strings from "line - 0" to "line - 14".
For some reasion "line - 15" to "line - 18" remain in the queue

**What I want:**

`items` to contain strings from "line - 0" to "line - 18" - all the strings from `queuestr`

Comment: why do you even need a queue when you want all the items? what are you actually trying to achieve? if you need batching, why not use `MoreLinq` and call `.Batch(3)`? besides that, the code will fail when `Count` is not a multiple of 3 ...

Comment: I think the value of `queuestr.Count` decreases as the loop value `i` increases, since you de-queue items from the queue. So at some point `i` will be higher than the number of items in the queue.

Comment: @Maarten, yes it does. I tried to set i<18, but this didn't solve my problem

Comment: Why not use `queuestr.Count > 0` as the loop-exit-condition? Keep adding items until the queue is empty. Even better, change it in a while loop.

Comment: @Maarten That'd still break if there wasn't a multiple of three items though.

Comment: @Servy Correct, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The check `i < queuestr.Count` is not logical. What is the relation between the two numbers? At some point the value of `i` will be higher than the number of items in the queue.

Better would be to use a while loop. The check `> 2` is to make sure you can de-queue three times.

```
while (queuestr.Count > 2) {
    items.Add(new queuestrtem {
        Item1 = queuestr.Dequeue(),
        Item2 = queuestr.Dequeue(),
        Item3 = queuestr.Dequeue(),
    });
}
```